# Elm: Multiple modules named maybe

Tags: elm, option-type

I'm running through a tutorial, and I'm trying to import the `Maybe` module, but am getting the below error:

```
I found multiple modules named 'Maybe'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Modules with that name were found in the following locations:

directory ././Maybe.elm
package elm-lang/core
```

How do I point at one of the above packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Maybe` module from the `elm-lang/core` package is [imported by default](https://github.com/elm-lang/core#default-imports), so if that's what you're trying to import, there's no need to do so.

I can't be sure what is causing the name collision without seeing which packages you have installed, but if you've created your own module called `Maybe`, I suggest renaming it. Module name patterns such as `NameOfDirectory.NameOfModule` are common in Elm (in fact, I think they're somewhat enforced).

Comment: I see. I simply had a file called maybe.elm, and that was causing the conflict. I renamed it and that fixed it.